# Is there anyway to transfer the Office 2013 license after upgrading from Windows 7 to 8?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office

I recently had to upgrade to windows 8 when windows 7 kept crashing.

I used a copy of office pro plus, the version that the University gave us (through Microsoft Dreamspark I think). The key had two activations but I also let a friend install it too so I don't think that the key will work again.

I still have access to the windows.old folder, so I was wondering if I could somehow transfer the license to the new installation of Windows 8.

Thanks.

Comment: Off Topic - not programming related.

Comment: Two activations does not mean two licenses. Letting your friend install it to was doing something akin to stealing. Not cool. This may be the price you end up paying.

Comment: Your friend will have to remove it from their computer to activate it on your new installation your friend can buy his own copy.

Answer (score 1):

Key should still work, if not, just call the 1800 number and explain, they'll let you activate again most likely.

Comment: "they'll let you activate again most likely" - *Maybe*, although as Joel rightly points out above, sharing your key with others is not a use case MS will be happy to overlook.

Comment: Well yeah, don't tell them that, just say you need to install again. Say you had to reformat. Microsoft's less sophisticated than you think.